# Is it possible to transfer state between windows in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

According to the Apache beam documentation:
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers

`All state for a key is scoped to the current window. This means that the first time a key is seen for a given window any state reads will return empty, and that a runner can garbage collect state when a window is completed.`

I have a use case where the output of the current window needs to be accessed by the next window.

The windows are fixed 5 second windows and a calculation is performed which outputs the total distance covered within this window. I need this distance to be added to the next windows total. Currently I achieve this by writing the total to a database and reading it in the next window but this slows processing down too much.

So my question is, is it possible for state to be transmitted between windows.
Or would I have to set up a global window with the 5 second windows inside of the overarching global window?
Is that possible?

Comment: Before I write out a full answer, what do you mean when you say need the distance in the next window? Like each window's distance includes only its own distance and the previous window's distance? (i.e. [Sliding Windows](http://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#sliding-time-windows)) Or the distance at each window is the full sum up to that point? The second sounds like you could just change back to a global window and then use a Combine to add all distances (potentially with triggers to fire early results).

Comment: The data is a stream of vehicle odometer readings so we use a short window find the min and maximum values get the difference and then sum these differences for each vehicle. This sum the "window distance" is added to the total that comes out of the previous window to get the current total distance which is sent on.

Comment: Seems that the combine proposed by @DanielOliveira is the better option for you. Another Idea, if you are receiving the odometer data, why don't you just subtract the last bigger value received from the smaller value of the first window ? it will always give you the total distance and you don't have to be writing always the last received distance (It can also prevent you from errors in the total distance if some windows is lost).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the issue I'm having is that I can't share information between windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to transfer state between windows, and if there is some form of workaround I would not recommend it as it goes against the Beam model and may have unintended behavior.

However it shouldn't be too difficult to get the result you want while adhering to the Beam model. The specifics might depend a bit on how you intend to use the summed distances, but the first step remains the same: **Switch the window back to the Global window, so we can aggregate over all elements.**

Java example:

```
PCollection<Integer> distances = ... // The windowed distances.
PCollection<Integer> globalDistances =
        distances.apply(Window.<Integer>into(new GlobalWindows()));
```

Now that the distances are in a global window, the following transform depends on how you would like the result.

**Option 1: Combine with Triggers.** A simple approach is to use a Combine like [`Sum`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/aggregation/sum/) to add up all the distances, while adding a repeating trigger to the window to repeatedly fire early so results are regularly updated. This is mainly a solution for Streaming pipelines, as early firing triggers have no effect in Batch pipelines. See the [Triggers section](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers) of the programming guide for details.

Java example:

```
// Window fires a pane on every 10 elements received.
PCollection<Integer> globalDistances =
        distances.apply(Window.<Integer>into(new GlobalWindows())
                .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(10))));
PCollection<Int> summed = globalDistances.apply(Sum.integersGlobally())
```

**Option 2: Sum via State.** The other option is closer to your original intention. Write a custom DoFn using state, like a [CombiningState](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combiningstate), to sum up each element received and output the current sum. This outputs each step of the summation as an individual element instead of having to deal with early firing panes or anything like that. This is the best option if you explicitly need a separate element for each step of the summation, or if you have a Batch pipeline and can't use triggers.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just some additional clarification my example I'm dealing with is streaming. I assume if I use a global window I'd just have to keep track of the lowest incoming odometer reading for each vehicle in order to perform the distance calculation.